# Multiples contexts ef-core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

I'm working with EF Core and I decided split the DbContexts I'm using.
Everything is right but I notice that when I create the migrations for each context, EF tries to create the tables again even if the other context had created that table previously.
I think EF Core must be trying to *update* the tables instead of  trying to *create* them but I don't know why EF Core would do that.

AccountsContext :

```
 public class AccountsContext : BaseContext<AccountContext>
 {
        public AccountContext(DbContextOptions<AccountsContext> options): base (options){}
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasKey(a => a.id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property(a => a.Name).HasField("_name");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property(a => a.Role).HasField("_role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().OwnsOne(a => a.Password);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().OwnsOne(a => a.Email);
    }
}
```

CampaignContext :

```
public class CampaignContext: BaseContext<CampaignContext>
{
      public CampaignContext(DbContextOptions<CampaignContext> options): base (options){}

    public DbSet<Campaign> Campaing { get; set; }
    private DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Campaing>().ToTable("Campaings");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Campaing>().HasKey(a => a.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Campaing>().HasOne(c => c.Owner);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("Accounts");
  }
}
```

Here is the scaffold of the migration in the campaign context. EF Core looks like its trying to create the accounts table even if it already exists in the database.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I based in this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx  but ported in ef-core because i want to implement bounded contexts suggested in DDD

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Hi thanks for your observations Amy i always post the code as text but how i think that my problem is not the code so i think the problem is how ef-core is doing  the migration I thought that in this ocation was no necesary but i make the change.

Comment: Forget about "bounded" contexts. `DbContext` is EF (Core) equivalent of a database. Single database - single `DbContext`. All attempts (hacks) to avoid that will just cause you troubles.

Answer (score 0):

you should specify the Context you want to use by

`dotnet ef Update Database -Context DbContext`

Answer (score 0):

each context in Ef core considered as a separated database so you are putting that table in both of the databases I don't know why you are trying to do that but it is normal that you see the table in both migrations

Comment: yes i understand each db context represent a database but i want to do something like Jon P Smith describe [here](https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCore.GenericBizRunner/wiki/Using-multiple-DbContexts) in the example you can see what i mean
the posibility of share a table in different context.

Comment: found a similar issue here is link to it this might help u solve your problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986756/efcore-map-2-entities-to-same-table)